# Indent multiple lines the same way as plain text editor

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

Sometimes I have code blocks in my Word documents, and I want to work with them without copying to plain text editor.

Namely, I want to have an ability to indent/unindent multiple lines of code using "Tab" character. This task is very simple in any plain text editor or IDE, but for the sake of clarity, I will show it here. Tabs are shown as black arrows:

[image]

1. Initial state
2. Using the Shift key or mouse, I selected a part of JavaScript function
3. Then I pressed Tab key on my keyboard
4. Selected lines were indented by inserting tab character on each line.

How it could be done with VBA?

Since I don't post any code (as evidence of my own efforts), I don't expect to get something completely working. But at least, I hope to get an understanding "how" it could be done.

---

As David suggested, I recorded a macro. Here how it looks:

```
Sub Indentator()
    Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
End Sub
```

The problem is, that I don't understand how to get it work for multiple lines. If I select them, this macro (and it was not surprise for me) just inserts "Tab" instead of selection.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried recording a macro and modify the code?
I use it several times to know the code lines that makes an specific action.

Comment: @DavidG. Good idea. I updated the post.

Comment: microsoft notepad does not behave in that way. this feature is useful in programming editors, not so much in word processors where indentation is done by paragraph.   .... you could have a macro that inserts a tab at the beginning of every selected line.

Comment: Try `Selection.Paragraphs.LeftIndent = 72`

Comment: examine the `selection` object tree in the Watch window.  one of its properties may be a collection of lines  .... if there is such a collection, then you could iterate through the collection and add a tab to the beginning of each of the lines

Comment: @DavidG. It indents using Word's build-in indentation. That's mean, after such code block will be someday copied to IDE, indentation will be lost.

Comment: @jsotola Very interesting. Thank you!

Comment: or `paragraphs` collection as answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the macros are named `IncreaseIndent` and `DecreaseIndent`, they can be run using the Increase and Decrease Indent buttons on the Home tab.

```
Sub IncreaseIndent()
    If Selection.Start = Selection.End Then
        Selection.InsertBefore vbTab
        Selection.Start = Selection.End
    Else
        Dim p As Paragraph
        For Each p In Selection.Paragraphs
            p.Range.InsertBefore vbTab
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Sub DecreaseIndent()
    If Selection.Start = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start Then
        Selection.Start = Selection.Start + 1
    End If
    Dim p As Paragraph, c As Range
    For Each p In Selection.Paragraphs
        Set c = p.Range.Characters(1)
        If c.Text = vbTab Then c.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Reference https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrint.htm

Answer (score 2):

Insert a tab character at the start of each paragraph in the selection:

```
Sub Indentator()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    For Each para In Selection.Paragraphs
        para.Range.InsertBefore vbTab
    Next
End Sub
```

(This assumes that each of your code "lines" is a new "paragraph" in Word, which it usually would be if you are intending to copy/paste this to/from actual code.)

Comment: Сould you please explain, why it works a bit strange for non-selected lines? That's what I mean: [link](https://i.imgur.com/QjBdoIv.png). If I put the caret to some already indented line, indentation will be performed with caret moving. But if put the caret in the very beginning of the line, the caret will not be moved. Why?

Comment: @johnc.j. If the cursor is in front of the paragraph, then inserting a tab in front of the paragraph is inserting it after the cursor. (Or think of it in terms of characters - if you insert a character "t" into the string "cpppp" just before the first "p", you end up with "ctpppp", i.e. "c" is not moved).  But if the cursor is in the middle of the paragraph, then inserting the tab in front of the paragraph moves the cursor.  (Again with characters, inserting a "t" before the first "p" in "ppcpp" gives "tppcpp", i.e. the "c" has been moved with the rest of the characters.)